# Django project run broker and woker in remote host

Tags: django, celery, worker, broker

I have a Django project, and it runs celery using Rabbitmq as a broker in a remote server. I wonder if I can run worker on the remote server too. I do not want to run broker and worker in one remote server, but run it on seperated remote server. I wonder if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This is completely possible.  Just make sure that both the celery worker and the django web server are pointed to the same broker.

Comment: Django Web server is pointing broker(RabbitMQ), but I don't know how to make worker to point broker. does Django-celery support that?

Comment: Just in your celery worker configuration, you can set the `broker_url` to the rabbit mq server.  If you can post your celery.py configuration, I can show you how to do that.